# Undefined constant with debug set to true

Tags: wp-debug

I have used to following code to change the location of 'single' Wordpress templates.

```
define(SINGLE_PATH, TEMPLATEPATH.'/single/');
add_filter('single_template', 'lsmwp_custom_single');

function lsmwp_custom_single($single) {

  global $wp_query, $post;

  if ($post->post_type == "cpt_operator"){
      if(file_exists(SINGLE_PATH . '/single-' . $post->post_type . '.php'))
          return SINGLE_PATH . '/single-' . $post->post_type . '.php';
  }

  foreach((array)get_the_category() as $cat) :
      if(file_exists(SINGLE_PATH . '/single-cat-' . $cat->slug . '.php'))
        return SINGLE_PATH . '/single-cat-' . $cat->slug . '.php';
      elseif(file_exists(SINGLE_PATH . '/single-cat-' . $cat->term_id . '.php'))
        return SINGLE_PATH . '/single-cat-' . $cat->term_id . '.php';
  endforeach;

  if(file_exists(SINGLE_PATH . '/single.php'))
    return SINGLE_PATH . '/single.php';
  elseif(file_exists(SINGLE_PATH . '/default.php'))
    return SINGLE_PATH . '/default.php';
  return $single;
}
```

The function works fine and Worpdress is looking for single templates in the new folder. However if I have `WP_DEBUG` set to `TRUE` I receive the following error:

> Use of undefined constant SINGLE_PATH - assumed 'SINGLE_PATH'

Have I gone wrong with my function somewhere?

Comment: You do have a huge amount of issues here, will post an answer. ;-)

Comment: Great, looking forward to seeing where Iv gone wrong :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a lot of issues here.

- Stay away from defining globals and constants if you can. The global scope is an evil place to be. WordPress has made a huge mess of the global scope already, don't make it a bigger mess than it already is. You can make use a static variable inside your function/filter
- Avoid using `TEMPLATEPATH`. You should use `get_template_directory_uri()`. IIRC, there was a notice somewhere of future depreciation of `TEMPLATEPATH`, but citation is needed on this as `locate_template()` for one still uses `TEMPLATEPATH`. But anyway, use `get_template_path_directory_uri()` for parent themes, that is the correct way
- You would want to use `locate_template()` to search for a specific template, and not `file_exists`. Let WordPress handle WordPress stuff. Only use PHP (*or for that matter custom SQL*) if WordPress does not provide a native function/means of doing something. The native functions are there to take care of other stuff that you might be forgetting about when using custom PHP

  In the new context, if we use `locate_template()`, we do not need to use `get_template_directory_uir()`. `locate_template()` by default handles that section for us. That is why it is important to use native WordPress functions to handle a specific job

  You have a double slash in your generated filenames. Your constant is `/single/` and your file name is `/single.php`, which renders `/single//single.php`. You need to remove a slash in iether of the two to avoid the duplicate slash
- `single-{$post_type}.php` is by default used for custom post types
- If you are working with the post object of a single post page outside the loop, rather use `get_queried_object()` which is much more reliable than the `$post` global.
- Although your syntax is valid, it is better to use curly brackets (`{}`) instead of the `:` and `endforeach` syntax. This also goes for the syntax of your conditionl statements. I prefer curlies as they are easy to debug should my code fail
- If you create a custom hierarchy like you have, always set `index.php` as your ultimate fallback template as `index.php` is required by all themes

Lets properly rewrite your code (***NOTE:*** I'm using closures which have the downside that it cannot be removed by `remove_filter()`, so change it to normal spaghetti if you wish.). We will be using the logic inside `get_single_template()` to help us here

(*The code requires PHP 5.4+ <strike>and is **untested**</strike>*)

```
add_filter( 'single_template', function ( $template )
{
    // Get the current single post object
    $post = get_queried_object();
    // Set our 'constant' folder path
    $path = 'single/';

    // Set our variable to hold our templates
    $templates = [];

    // Lets handle the custom post type section
    if ( 'post' !== $post->post_type ) {
        $templates[] = $path . 'single-' . $post->post_type . '-' . $post->post_name . '.php';
        $templates[] = $path . 'single-' . $post->post_type . '.php';
    }

    // Lets handle the post post type stuff
    if ( 'post' === $post->post_type ) {
        // Get the post categories
        $categories = get_the_category( $post->ID );
        // Just for incase, check if we have categories
        if ( $categories ) {
            foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
                // Create possible template names
                $templates[] = $path . 'single-cat-' . $category->slug . '.php';
                $templates[] = $path . 'single-cat-' . $category->term_id . '.php';
            } //endforeach
        } //endif $categories
    } // endif  

    // Set our fallback templates
    $templates[] = $path . 'single.php';
    $templates[] = $path . 'default.php';
    $templates[] = 'index.php';

    /**
     * Now we can search for our templates and load the first one we find
     * We will use the array ability of locate_template here
     */
    $template = locate_template( $templates );

    // Return the template rteurned by locate_template
    return $template;
});
```

### EDIT

The code above is tested and working as expected.

### EDIT 2 - Pre PHP 5.4 (*T_Rex still roam the darkness*)

```
add_filter( 'single_template', function ( $template )
{
    // Get the current single post object
    $post = get_queried_object();
    // Set our 'constant' folder path
    $path = 'single/';

    // Set our variable to hold our templates
    $templates = array();

    // Lets handle the custom post type section
    if ( 'post' !== $post->post_type ) {
        $templates[] = $path . 'single-' . $post->post_type . '-' . $post->post_name . '.php';
        $templates[] = $path . 'single-' . $post->post_type . '.php';
    }

    // Lets handle the post post type stuff
    if ( 'post' === $post->post_type ) {
        // Get the post categories
        $categories = get_the_category( $post->ID );
        // Just for incase, check if we have categories
        if ( $categories ) {
            foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
                // Create possible template names
                $templates[] = $path . 'single-cat-' . $category->slug . '.php';
                $templates[] = $path . 'single-cat-' . $category->term_id . '.php';
            } //endforeach
        } //endif $categories
    } // endif  

    // Set our fallback templates
    $templates[] = $path . 'single.php';
    $templates[] = $path . 'default.php';
    $templates[] = 'index.php';

    /**
     * Now we can search for our templates and load the first one we find
     * We will use the array ability of locate_template here
     */
    $template = locate_template( $templates );

    // Return the template rteurned by locate_template
    return $template;
});
```

Comment: When you said I had gone wrong I thought my syntax was off, was not expecting a whole new function! Another great answer, I did not know about the danger of the settings variables in global scope, will be wary in future. Many thanks

Comment: I think somethings gone wrong somewhere, I just received 500 error

Comment: That is strange, you have something which is breaking something else in your theme or in a plugin

Comment: I am running php 5.3.3

Comment: See my updated edit 2, had a small syntax error, can see it is getting late ;-)

Comment: Perfect! Thats the ticket.. note: syntax error at '$templates = array' missed the (). Oh and i'm more of a V_Lociraptor caught in the red tape of management :) Thanks for your help bud

Comment: Great answer(s). +10 for `get_queried_object()`; it's good stuff. (Figurative) -1 for the `if{}` > `if:endif;` though! Especially if you're going to write `if{...}//endif`!

Comment: @Will I think syntax comes down to personal choice. As my code stands, it is easier for me to debug, specially when you start nesting. As I said, the OP's syntax is perfectly valid. Most code editors don't accept the `endif` type syntax, so that is the reason for my syntax. The additional `//endif` is just example for OP

Comment: @James glad it worked. Jip, I missed that, think it is because it is so late here now, hahaha. Enjoy ;-)

Comment: @Will code should always be readable and maintainable and easy to debug. Coding standards are not just black or white, it does allow for readability and maintainability ;-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen Absolutely personal choice. Was 111% razzing. =)

Answer (score 2):

A note about the actual message you're getting from PHP. When you define a constant, you should do it with a string.

```
define(SINGLE_PATH, TEMPLATEPATH.'/single/');
```

The first parameter is the constant name - when you call `define` the constant doesn't exist yet.

This would take care of the message from PHP:

```
define('SINGLE_PATH', TEMPLATEPATH.'/single/');
```

A full example of using a constant:

```
<?php
define( 'SOME_CONSTANT', true );

if ( SOME_CONSTANT ) {
    echo 'Constant was true';
}
```

Also

> if I have 'WP_DEBUG' set to TRUE

Notice how `WP_DEBUG` is defined:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

But in your code later you would call it without quotes:

```
var_dump( WP_DEBUG ); // bool(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "template-parts" folder instead this will work. -function.php

```
add_filter( 'single_template', function ( $template )
{
    // Get the current single post object
    $post = get_queried_object();
    // Set our 'constant' folder path
    $path = 'template-parts/';

// Set our variable to hold our templates
$templates = array();

// Lets handle the custom post type section
if ( 'post' !== $post->post_type ) {
    $templates[] = $path . 'content-' . $post->post_type . '-' . $post->post_name . '.php';
    $templates[] = $path . 'content-' . $post->post_type . '.php';
}

// Lets handle the post post type stuff
if ( 'post' === $post->post_type ) {
    // Get the post categories
    $categories = get_the_category( $post->ID );
    // Just for incase, check if we have categories
    if ( $categories ) {
        foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
            // Create possible template names
            $templates[] = $path . 'content-' . $category->slug . '.php';
            $templates[] = $path . 'content-' . $category->term_id . '.php';
        } //endforeach
    } //endif $categories
} // endif  

// Set our fallback templates
$templates[] = $path . 'single.php';
$templates[] = 'index.php';

/**
 * Now we can search for our templates and load the first one we find
 * We will use the array ability of locate_template here
 */
$template = locate_template( $templates );

// Return the template rteurned by locate_template
return $template;
});
```